# Changed Secure and unsecure URL on a View. Now admin redirects to the unsecure URL of the View. Why?

Tags: magento2, configuration, url, redirect

I have 3 stores setup on Magento 2 as follows:

```
Website --> store_1 --> store_1_view
Website --> store_2 --> store_2_view
Website --> store_3 --> store_3_view
```

I have changed the unsecure and secure URL in "Stores / Configuration" of one of the views which points to another domain. I think it was the default store.

As soon as I saved the configuration, the "admin" page redirected to the View unsecure URL.

I can not get back into admin as it continually redirects me to the other domain.

Where in the database can I change the settings of the view URL back to the default URL?

I have looked through the database tables, but cannot find the correct table.

Comment: welcome to MSE. please check in core_config_data table. there you can find urls for all stores

Comment: Thanks. I found core_config_data and changed the values, but it still redirects to the other domain. How do I clear the cache without accessing the admin panel?

Comment: its good to listen from you. you can delete those cache in root folder. goto var then cache. delete folder named cache.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response @TejabhagavanKollepara. Worked perfectly... And everyone below that answered.

Comment: good here this from you. but i want to suggest you that please becareful on every action you performed in server.

Comment: I have just posted answer . please check once, please upvote and accept if that works.

Answer (score 1):

In your database !! you need to check **core_config_data** table.

It have listed all the **secure** and **unsecure** base urls.

To change the unsecure url you need to change value of **web/unsecure/base_url** path.

Same way to change the secure url you need to change value of **web/secure/base_url** Path.

then run **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** command if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's `core_config_data` table, run this query:

`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%base%url%';`

Dont forget to clear your cache!

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your cpanel and goto your database through phpmyadmin
2. check for the table `core_config_data`
3. change the secure url at web/unsecure/base_url path and unsecure base url at web/unsecure/base_url path from here.

**Edit from @Todd Robards's(author) comment:**

4. Delete cache from root folder by go to your public_html-->var-->cache. Delete this cache folder